# How to call a function from a prefab button?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab button and a non prefab Game manager. I want this button to be cloned and call a function in Game Manager. How can I do that?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @BugFinder normal things, create a function in game manager then put it in button's list

Comment: That really didn't answer his question on what you tried, for me normal things might be the solution you are looking for but for you that wouldn't be a normal thing.  Care to show what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
[SerializeField]
private GameObject buttonPrefab;

[SerializeField]
private Transform canvas;

public void CloneButton()
{
    var buttonComponent = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, canvas).GetComponent<Button>();
    buttonComponent.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
}

public void TaskOnClick()
{
    // things happen when the button clicked
}
```

You have to give a reference for the prefab, and the canvas object as a parent for the button via inspector.

Comment: You can get rid of the GetComponent call if you stored your prefab as a Button instead of a gameObject.